# How to correct a tag mismatch error?

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I've created a `network` xml file to be parsed into a Java application. But I get the following error when I validate the xml file:

"Line 71, Column 14: end tag for element "location" which is not open"

To debug this, I checked my opening and closing tags, but I don't see any that are in error.

Can anyone spot where the tag error is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<network>
  <locations>
   <location>
    <location name="Tiberius"/>
    <location description="You are in the Kingdom of Tiberias at the start of your journey.."/>
    <objects>
        <object type = "sword" life = "-0.5"/>
        <object type = "food" life = "+0.5"/>
        <object type = "medicine" life = "+1.0"/>
        <object type = "ale" life = "+0.2"/>
        <object type = "shield" life = "+0.4"/>
    </objects>
    <character>
        <character type = "Saracen" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Hospitaller" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Templar" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Principality of Antioch" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Order of Saint" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Lazarus" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Ayyubids" life = "10"/>
    </character>
    <exits>
        <exit name="Jerusalem" direction="S"/>
    </exits>
   </location>
   <location>
    <location name="Jerusalem"/>
    <location description="You are in the Kingdom of Jerusalem.."/>
    <objects>
        <object type = "sword" life = "-0.5"/>
        <object type = "food" life = "+0.5"/>
        <object type = "medicine" life = "+1.0"/>
        <object type = "ale" life = "+0.2"/>
        <object type = "shield" life = "+0.4"/>
    </objects>
    <character>
        <character type = "Saracen" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Hospitaller" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Templar" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Principality of Antioch" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Order of Saint" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Lazarus" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Ayyubids" life = "10"/>
    </character>
    <exits>
        <exit name="Lod" direction="W"/>
    </exits>
   </location>
   <location name="Lod"/>
    <location description="You are in the Kingdom of Lod.."/>
    <objects>
        <object type = "sword" life = "-0.5"/>
        <object type = "food" life = "+0.5"/>
        <object type = "medicine" life = "+1.0"/>
        <object type = "ale" life = "+0.2"/>
        <object type = "shield" life = "+0.4"/>
    </objects>
    <character>
        <character type = "Saracen" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Hospitaller" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Knights Templar" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Principality of Antioch" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Order of Saint" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Lazarus" life = "10"/>
        <character type = "Ayyubids" life = "10"/>
    </character>
    <exits>
        <exit name="Haifa" direction="N"/>
    </exits>
   </location>
  </locations>
  <edges>
   <edge>
    <edge direction="S" from = "Tiberius" to="Jerusalem" weight="10" danger="7"/> 
   </edge>
   <edge>
    <edge direction="W" from = "Jerusalem" to="Lod" weight="8" danger="10"/> 
   </edge>
   <edge>
    <edge direction="N" from = "Lod" to="Haifa" weight="23" danger="5"/> 
   </edge>
  </edges>
</network>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of this line  `<location name="Lod"/>` add  opening tag `<location>`, hope this would fix your issue. Let me know if you need any help